# How to input an Int argument to the forward function of torch::jit::script::Module

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch, torchscript

I converted `nn.Module` with torch.jit.script and saved it in .pt format.
The forward function in that module has an Int argument.

```
    def forward(self, x: Tensor, id : int) -> Tensor:
        print(id)
        x = self._forward(x)
        return x
```

When I load the module in c++, I pass the Tensor like this,

```
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 3, 224, 224}));
at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
```

but how should I write it for Int?
Which struct should I use?

Answer (score 0):

My forward:

```
def forward(self, t0, t1, i):
    ...
```

If you try to input an `int` to `forward()` you will get the following when exporting your model to torchscript with `jit.trace`:

```
Type 'Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, int]' cannot be traced. Only Tensors and (possibly nested) Lists, Dicts, and Tuples of Tensors can be traced
```

So, you need to transform your `int` type to `tensor` by for example

```
int a = 0;
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 3, 640, 256}));
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 3, 640, 256}));
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, a}));
at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
```